# 正しいwheelファイルかどうかを、テストコードで確認したいです。 Travis CI上で、どのようにして実現すべきでしょうか？

Tags: python, travis-ci, pypi

## 背景

PythonでCLIコマンドを作成しています。

- Python 3.7
- Travis CIでテストコードを実行

以下のコマンドでwheelファイルを生成して、PyPIにパッケージを登録しています。

```py
    pipenv run python setup.py check --strict
    pipenv run python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
    pipenv run twine upload dist/* --repository-url https://test.pypi.org/legacy/ --verbose
```

#### 起きた問題

不正なwheelファイルを、PyPIに登録してしまいました。
原因は、新しくモジュールを追加した際に、`__init__.py`を追加し忘れたことです。
この状態でwheelファイルを作成したため、wheelファイルに新しく追加したモジュールが含まれていませんでした。

#### 質問

正しいwheelファイルかどうかを、テストコードで確認したいです。
Travis CI上で、どのようにして実現すべきでしょうか？

以下のようにwheelファイルを生成してから、`pip install`して、bashでテストコードを書けばよいでしょうか？

```py
python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
pip install dist/samplecli-xxx.whl
./test-samplecli.sh
```

test-samplecli.sh

```sh
actual=`sample'
assert ${actual} ${expected}
```

Comment: 質問に合っているか？使えるのか？何処に何時組み込むのか？等は不明ですが、`__init__.py`の有無に限れば、[mypy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_line.html#import-discovery) のオプションに機能があるようです。[python/mypy#1645](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1645) の議論が元になっているようです。

Comment: 同じく使えるかわかりませんが、CIのキーワードでこれが見つかりました。[ContinuumIO/ciocheck](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/ciocheck) これ自身が使っているのか、組み込めるようになっているのか分かりませんが、travis用設定ファイルもあるようです。[ciocheck/.travis.yml](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/ciocheck/blob/master/.travis.yml)